# Ansible: overriding dictionary variables in extra-vars

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible playbook I have a nested variable declaration as shown below in a variable file.

```
repo:
  branch: int
  url: git@github:user/repo.git
  dest: "/var/code"
```

How would I override the branch param in extra-vars? I tried something like this below but it didn't work.

```
 --extra-vars "repo.branch=exec_refactor"
```

neither this

```
 --extra-vars "repo[branch]=exec_refactor"
```

using JSON representation like below results in overriding the entire `repo` node and hence repo.branch is successfully overridden but both repo.url and repo.dest becomes undefined.

```
 --extra-vars '{"repo":{"branch":"exec_refactor"}}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To merge dicts, you need to set `hash_behaviour=merge` in your `ansible.cfg`. But it is not recommended to do this since pretty much all roles you find on Ansible Galaxy do expect the default value `replace` and might run crazy.

See [`hash_behaviour`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) in the docs.

I once had a similar problem and wrote an action plugin to solve it: [include_vars_merged](https://gist.github.com/udondan/b730206056a018cf9838). It is no out-of-the-box solution for your problem because Ansible in any case will override the dict with the one from `--extra-vars` and using my plugin, you would again override that single value you passed in `--extra-vars`. But it should not be too hard to modify the plugin and only add new values instead of overriding values. I think switching parameters in line 34 & 40 in `include_vars_merged.py` should already do it.

Comment: Thanks, Any idea why this feature was not included? I have raised a feature request for this.

Comment: I'm also facing a similar problem, @rogue-one did you find any solution to this?